# Setting and retrieving DateTime using Datetime-local HTML type

Tags: node.js, datetime, ecmascript-6, momentjs, datetime-format

Without using momentjs on client-side. I need to properly save the date/time to the db and pull it back, followed by converting it to local.

I noticed the material-ui datepicker took care of this before but now I need to do it myself.

The html input 'datetime-local' doesn't like receiving timezone so I'm not sure how to do the whole flow.

I think I need to get UTC date on the client side like this for the db (?)
`2021-10-26T01:14:27.920+00:00`

And somehow on turn it into something input 'datetime-local' will accept.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive in the folllowing ways

```
// Create date object from datetime string
var date = new Date('2021-10-26T01:14:27.920+00:00');

// Coverting local datetime back to UTC
console.log(date.toUTCString()); // Output "Tue, 26 Oct 2021 01:14:27 GMT"

// Coverting to local datetime 
console.log(date.toString());  // Output "Tue Oct 26 2021 06:44:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

// Coverting to local timezone 
console.log(date.toLocaleString()); // Output "10/26/2021, 6:44:27 AM"
```

Comment: Related JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/katheer_mizal/a2y7jhsk/10/

Comment: Thanks @Katheer. The Date object was what I needed  to get local time :)

But do you know what format would fill this input from that?

``` <input className="datetime-input" type="datetime-local" value={date} />```

Comment: Usual type="datetime-local" is providing following format 2017-06-01T08:30, 
More details please check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: Check the Updated fiddle to retrive date time from input[type="datetime-local"] element: https://jsfiddle.net/katheer_mizal/a2y7jhsk/18/